# CHECK constraint in SQL Server not allowing to exceed value from foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    ID int IDENTITY UNIQUE,
    length int not null
)

CREATE TABLE test2
(
    ID int IDENTITY UNIQUE,
    test1number int references test1(ID),
    distance int not null
)
```

Example: lets insert into test1 values 1 and 100 (ID=1 and length=100). Now lets insert into test2 values 1 as ID and test1number=1 as reference from test1. I want to create a constraint which will not allow to write distance bigger than 100 (length from test1).

Any other way than procedure?

Comment: If there are *multiple* rows referencing a single row in `test1`, is the constraint "no row may have a `distance` greater than `length`" or is it "the sum of the `distance` values may not exceed `length`"?

Comment: first:)) distance can not be greater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for individual rows, and we don't need to assert some property about all rows with the same `test1number` values then one way to do it is this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    ID int IDENTITY UNIQUE,
    length int not null,
    constraint UQ_test1_Length_XRef UNIQUE (ID,Length)
)
go
CREATE TABLE _test2
(
    ID int IDENTITY UNIQUE,
    test1number int references test1(ID),
    _test1length int not null,
    distance int not null,
    constraint FK_test2_test1_length_xref foreign key (test1number,_test1length) 
            references test1 (ID,length) on update cascade,
    constraint CK_length_distance CHECK (distance <= _test1length)
)
go
create view test2
as
    select ID,test1number,distance from _test2
go
create trigger T_I_t2 on test2
instead of insert
as
    insert into _test2(test1number,_test1length,distance)
    select test1number,length,distance
    from inserted i inner join test1 t on i.test1number = t.id
go
```

We only need the view and trigger if you're trying to hide the existence of this extra column in the `_test2` table from your users.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. What means _ before test1length? I also try to google for it

Comment: @user3162968 - it's got no special meaning. I tend to use `_` as a prefix for any tables/columns/etc that I'm not planning to expose to my users. So the intent of the above code is that the users of this database still just access `test1(ID,length)` and `test2(ID,test1number,distance)` and have no knowledge of the `_test1` table, nor the `_test1length` column.